# sync.WaitGroup - why one go routine comes after .wait()

Tags: go

From the following I get:
Packing received cake:  Strawberry Cake 
Packing received cake:  Strawberry Cake 
Packing received cake:  Strawberry Cake 
Packing received cake:  Strawberry Cake 
We are done!
Packing received cake:  Strawberry Cake

I did not expect "We are done!" to be second last?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    // "strconv"
    // "time"
    "sync"
)

func makeCakeAndSend(cs chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    cakeName := "Strawberry Cake "
    cs <- cakeName
    wg.Done()
}

func receiveCakeAndPack(cs chan string) {
    for s := range cs {
        fmt.Println("Packing received cake: ", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    cs := make(chan string)

    wg.Add(5)

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        go makeCakeAndSend(cs, &wg)
    }

    // go receiveCakeAndPack(cs)

    go func() {
        for s := range cs {
            fmt.Println("Packing received cake: ", s)
        }
        close(cs)
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("We are done!")

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly normal. The `wg.Wait()` makes sure that all goroutines finished sending data to the channel before we continue, it doesn't synchronize the prints of "Packing received cake".

When everyone has finished sending the data down the channel, the channel has one item in it, right? but the Waitgroup is finished.

So you have a race condition where the main goroutine continues to "we are done" and the receiving goroutine receives and prints. This is not synchronized and you have no guarantee which will happen first.

Comment: What if I need to use values from all go routines before proceeding -  finished sending vs  finished receiving. Do you know?

Comment: then you can close the channel after wg.Wait and the receive loop will exit.

Comment: You could also move `wg.Done()`: If it's not done when you post the item to the channel, but when it's actually processed, then you should be calling `wg.Done()` in your anonymous channel consumer (after printing `Packing received cake`).